# Visual Asset Delivery

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, user-interface, user-experience

How do you or your company require designers to deliver their assets to coders?  Do they deliver a PSD?  A series of 24-bit PNGs?

If you are a coder, what would you include in a best-practice guideline to designers?  If you are a designer, what questions would you like to see answered in such a document?

Here are some ideas:

- Generally:

  - include designs for mouse-over and mouse-down states for all
    buttons and other interactive elements, as well as the normal state.
  - for toggle buttons, this can also include different states for
    both *selected* and *unselected* modes, for 6 states total: normal,
    over, down.
  - in drop-downs, lists, etc, please design a selected and unselected
    state for *each* item, if appropriate, especially where the content
    varies.
  - Flash is strictly an sRGB colorspace.  If creating assets for
    Flash, make sure that your deliverables look how you expect it in
    sRGB.
- If delivering assets as a PSD, please:

  - label all layers clearly.
  - make sure that the dimensions of your document exactly match the
    dimensions of the application

What else would you include in a Visual Asset Delivery Best Practices document?

Comment: I do it all myself. Let the artists do what they do best. The I do because they generally won't understand what needs to be done and in the time it takes to explain it it would be done already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When delivery is in the form of a PSD, I'm a huge fan of Layer Comps. They save me the trouble of having to click through the layer's palette to see how the comp should look at various states.